# How can I ingest data from Apache Avro into the Azure Data Explorer?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, data-ingestion

for several days I'm trying to ingest Apache Avro formatted data from a blob storage into the Azure Data Explorer.

I'm able to reference the toplevel JSON-keys like `$.Body` (see red underlined example in the screenshot below), but when it goes to the nested JSON-keys, Azure fails to parse them properly and displays nothing (as seen in the green column: I would expect `$.Body.entityId` to reference the key "entityId" inside the Body-JSON).

Many thanks in advance for any help!

[Here is a screenshot of the azure data explorer web interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPSKx.png)

### Edit 1

I already tried to increase the "Nested Levels" Option to 2, but all I got [is this error message with no further details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2n8w.png). The error message won't even disappear when I decrease the Level back to 1. I have to cancel and start the process all over agein.

I just recognize that the auto-generated columns have some strange types. Seems like they add up to the type `string`... This seems a little odd to me either.

### Edit 2

Here is some kql-Code.

This is the schema of my input `.avro` file, what I get from my Eventhub-Capture:

```
{
  SequenceNumber: ...,
  Offset: ...,
  EnqueuedTimeUTC: ...,
  SystemProperties: ...,
  Properties: ...,
  Body: {
    entityId: ...,
    eventTime: ...,
    messageId: ...,
    data: ...
  }
}, ...
```

And with these ingestion commands I can't reference the inner JSON-keys. The toplevel keys work perfectly fine.

```
// Create table command
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
.create table ['test_table']  (['Body']:dynamic, ['entityId']:string)

// Create mapping command
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
.create table ['test_table'] ingestion apacheavro mapping 'test_table_mapping' '[{"column":"Body", "Properties":{"Path":"$.Body"}},{"column":"entityId", "Properties":{"Path":"$.Body.entityId"}}]'

// Ingest data into table command
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
.ingest async into table ['test_table'] (h'[SAS URL]') with (format='apacheavro',ingestionMappingReference='test_table_mapping',ingestionMappingType='apacheavro',tags="['503a2cfb-5b81-4c07-8658-639009870862']")
```

I would love to ingest the inner data fields on separate columns, instead of building any workaround with update policies.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Those little details we sometimes neglect to mention ... 

Comment: P.S. you usually get attention to your post only when it's first published. If you wish to draw attention to your updates, you better response to a specific answer or tag the relevant people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Following the OP updates

Here is the [Avro schema of an Event Hubs capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview#use-avro-tools).
As you can see, `Body` as of type `bytes`, so there is practically nothing you can do with it at this form, other than ingesting it As Is (as Dynamic).

```
{

    "type":"record",
    "name":"EventData",
    "namespace":"Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging",
    "fields":[
                 {"name":"SequenceNumber","type":"long"},
                 {"name":"Offset","type":"string"},
                 {"name":"EnqueuedTimeUtc","type":"string"},
                 {"name":"SystemProperties","type":{"type":"map","values":["long","double","string","bytes"]}},
                 {"name":"Properties","type":{"type":"map","values":["long","double","string","bytes"]}},
                 {"name":"Body","type":["null","bytes"]}
             ]
}
```

If you'll take a look on the ingested data, you'll see that the content of `Body` is arrays of integers.
Those integers are the decimal values of the characters that construct `Body`.

```
capture
| project Body
| take 3
```

| Body |
| --- |
| [123,34,105,100,34,58,32,34,56,49,55,98,50,99,100,57,45,97,98,48,49,45,52,100,51,53,45,57,48,51,54,45,100,57,55,50,51,55,55,98,54,56,50,57,34,44,32,34,100,116,34,58,32,34,50,48,50,49,45,48,56,45,49,50,84,49,54,58,52,56,58,51,50,46,53,57,54,50,53,52,34,44,32,34,105,34,58,32,48,44,32,34,109,121,105,110,116,34,58,32,50,48,44,32,34,109,121,102,108,111,97,116,34,58,32,48,46,51,57,56,53,52,52,56,55,52,53,57,56,57,48,55,57,55,125] |
| [123,34,105,100,34,58,32,34,57,53,100,52,100,55,56,48,45,97,99,100,55,45,52,52,57,50,45,98,97,54,100,45,52,56,49,54,97,51,56,100,52,56,56,51,34,44,32,34,100,116,34,58,32,34,50,48,50,49,45,48,56,45,49,50,84,49,54,58,52,56,58,51,50,46,53,57,54,50,53,52,34,44,32,34,105,34,58,32,49,44,32,34,109,121,105,110,116,34,58,32,56,56,44,32,34,109,121,102,108,111,97,116,34,58,32,48,46,54,53,53,51,55,51,51,56,49,57,54,53,50,52,52,49,125] |
| [123,34,105,100,34,58,32,34,53,50,100,49,102,54,54,53,45,102,57,102,54,45,52,49,50,49,45,97,50,57,99,45,55,55,56,48,102,101,57,53,53,55,48,56,34,44,32,34,100,116,34,58,32,34,50,48,50,49,45,48,56,45,49,50,84,49,54,58,52,56,58,51,50,46,53,57,54,50,53,52,34,44,32,34,105,34,58,32,50,44,32,34,109,121,105,110,116,34,58,32,49,57,44,32,34,109,121,102,108,111,97,116,34,58,32,48,46,52,53,57,54,49,56,54,51,49,51,49,50,50,52,50,50,51,125] |

`Body` can be converted to text using [make_string()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makestringfunction) and then parsed to JSON using [todynamic()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction)

```
capture
| project BodyJSON = todynamic(make_string(Body))
| take 3
```

| BodyJSON |
| --- |
| {"id":"817b2cd9-ab01-4d35-9036-d972377b6829","dt":"2021-08-12T16:48:32.5962540Z","i":0,"myint":20,"myfloat":"0.398544874598908"} |
| {"id":"95d4d780-acd7-4492-ba6d-4816a38d4883","dt":"2021-08-12T16:48:32.5962540Z","i":1,"myint":88,"myfloat":"0.65537338196524408"} |
| {"id":"52d1f665-f9f6-4121-a29c-7780fe955708","dt":"2021-08-12T16:48:32.5962540Z","i":2,"myint":19,"myfloat":"0.45961863131224223"} |

Comment: After some research I've done in the past week, I came to the same result, that the byte-array is the root cause of the problem. Thank you for your answers, that helped me a lot to analyse this issue...

Answer (score 2):

For those having the same issue, here is the workaround we currently use:

First, assume that we want to ingest the contents of the Body field from the avro file to the table `avro_destination`.

#### Step 1: Create an ingestion table

```
.create table avro_ingest(
    Body: dynamic
    // optional other columns, if you want...
)
```

#### Step 2: Create an update policy

```
.create-or-alter function
    with (docstring = 'Convert avro_ingest to avro_destination', folder='ingest')
    convert_avro_ingest() {
        avro_ingest
        | extend entityId = tostring(Body.entityId)
        | extend messageId = tostring(Body.messageId)
        | extend eventTime = todatetime(Body.eventTime)
        | extend data = Body.data
        | project entityId, messageId, eventTime, data
    }
```

```
.alter table avro_destination policy update
@'[{ "IsEnabled": true, "Source": "avro_ingest", "Query": "convert_avro_ingest()", "IsTransactional": false, "PropagateIngestionProperties": true}]'
```

#### Step 3: Ingest the .avro files into the `avro_ingest` table

...as seen in the Question, with one Column containing the whole Body-JSON per entry.

Comment: Hi, this answer actually worked out for me. If I select the "APACHE AVRO" format in the ingestion-tab of the portal (note that this is not the same as "AVRO"), it displays the contents of the Body-field as JSON (as seen in my very first screenshot, the red column). If this is misleading though, I can delete this answer. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Yep, you are right :-)  Please keep it

Answer (score 1):

Simply increase "Nested levels" to 2.

[image: Data ingestion]